# Launch MFC window inside wrapped DLL

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, wrapper

I'm trying to hook application, and launch it in my new MFC window. DLL (Wrapper) works very good, but I have problem with MFC... Full MFC code is inside "AST" - wrapper. Main application object has been created, but MFC window for this has not opened. I have control points (Message boxes) and thanks by this I know where code stop, this moment is inside InitInstance, in CCommandLineInfo -> ParseCommandLine and ProcessShellCommand. I don't know why, but at this moment AST have freeze, and i can't do anything.

```
BOOL CwelibApp::InitInstance(){
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);

InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);

CWinAppEx::InitInstance();

// Initialize OLE libraries
if (!AfxOleInit())
{
    AfxMessageBox(IDP_OLE_INIT_FAILED);
    return FALSE;
}

AfxEnableControlContainer();
EnableTaskbarInteraction(FALSE);

// Place all significant initialization in InitInstance
SetRegistryKey(_T("Local AppWizard-Generated Applications"));
LoadStdProfileSettings(4);  // Load standard INI file options (including MRU)


InitContextMenuManager();
InitKeyboardManager();
InitTooltipManager();

CMFCToolTipInfo ttParams;
ttParams.m_bVislManagerTheme = TRUE;
weApplication.GetTooltipManager()->SetTooltipParams(AFX_TOOLTIP_TYPE_ALL,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCToolTipCtrl), &ttParams);

CSingleDocTemplate* pDocTemplate;
pDocTemplate = new CSingleDocTemplate(
    IDR_MAINFRAME,
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCApplication2Doc),
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMainFrame),       // main SDI frame window
    RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCApplication2View));

if (!pDocTemplate)
    return FALSE;

Say::Box("Init MFC #1");

AddDocTemplate(pDocTemplate);

if(m_hInstance)
    Say::Box("m_hInstance");
Say::Box("Init MFC #2");

CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;
ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);  //Freeze...
Say::Box("Init MFC #3");

if (!ProcessShellCommand(cmdInfo))
    return FALSE;

Say::Box("Init MFC #4");

m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();

Say::Box("Init MFC #5");
return TRUE;};
```

Where is problem? How I can open MFC application inside DLL, with using CFrameWndEx, CWinAppEx?
I have "Use FMC in a Static Library" in Project defaults.

Comment: It's unclear, what you are asking. Are you trying to host a (3rd-party) application inside your application? If that's the case, then this is not easily possible, if at all.

Comment: I'm trying to host application inside my MFC window. My MFC window is created inside DLL. After run application (old window), MFC is launched, but it's freezed on after call method "ParseCommandLine". I don't know why :/ 
Small image showing how is to act:
https://i.imgur.com/9Jw99dx.png

Comment: You are probably running into a loader-lock race. See [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices) and use your debugger to verify this. Make sure to also read [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) The gist is, that you cannot safely host a window owned by a different thread in your frame window.

Comment: Probably you would have struck with the loading of resource.  The main application is a separate process having separate resource handle and dll will have a separate resource handle.